# "Cada empresa tem o valor que merece ser negociado" - isto está correto?

Tags: concordância-verbal, concordância-nominal

Estou lendo um livro e achei a frase:

> *Cada empresa tem o valor que merece ser negociado.*

Eu escreveria:

> Cada empresa tem o valor que merece ser **negociada**.

em concordância com "cada empresa".

Fiz uma pesquisa rápida no Google, e não achei nada. Apesar de adorar português, sempre erro algo, aqui, ali!

Estaria o livro correto?

==

Completo
[image]

Fonte: https://www.amazon.com.br/Valuation-Precificar-A%C3%A7%C3%B5es-Alexandre-P%C3%B3voa/dp/8535253750

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A frase está gramaticalmente correta. Se faz sentido no contexto, é que eu não posso dizer, porque não tenho o contexto. Uma maneira intuitiva de desmontar a frase é assim:

> Cada empresa tem o valor.
> Qual valor?
> O valor que merece ser negociado.

O constituinte *que merece ser negociado* é uma oração subordinada adjetiva restritiva que modifica o nome *valor*, e *o valor que merece ser negociado* é o complemento direto de *tem*.

A alternativa que tu propões ― “**cada empresa** tem o valor **que merece ser negociada**” ― é que é muito estranha; por duas razões. Nesse caso, a empresa é que merece ser negociada, mas a ordem dos termos é estranhíssima, porque a oração subordinada (a negrito) fica separada do nome que modifica; o normal seria:

> Cada empresa que merece ser negociada tem o valor

Depois, a empresa tem o valor? Qual valor? Na frase original, nós sabemos que é o valor que merece ser negociado.

Há casos em que a tua questão realmente se põe. Por exemplo, as duas frases seguintes estão corretas:

> (a) Comprei um banco de madeira muito rara.
> (b) Comprei um banco de madeira muito raro.

Em (a), a madeira é que é rara (à parte disso, o banco pode nem ter interesse; podemos querer desmontá-lo e aproveitar a madeira para outra coisa); em (b) o banco, que até pode ser de madeira barata, é que é raro. Repara que, ao contrário da tua alternativa, *muito raro/a* fica em qualquer dos casos junto ao nome que modifica, só *madeira* em (a), *banco de madeira* em (b).

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, estou processando, ainda sem entender muito! Era bom de português no ensino médio 

Comment: @Jorge, se incluíres na pergunta o contexto da frase, talvez eu possa dar mais alguma ajuda. Eu imagino que pelo contexto, tu entendes que a empresa é que merece ser negociada (a formulação normal para isso seria "a empresa que merece ser negociada tem..."), mas eu só posso dar opinião sobre isso se tiver o contexto.

Comment: Tangente: na construção de instrumentos musicais, há algumas madeiras muito boas que normalmente não se podem utilizar, porque as árvores respectivas são raras e estão protegidas (e muito bem). Então, pode-se aproveitar madeira de coisas antigas (móveis, etc) para fazer instrumentos dessa madeira. :)

Comment: @ANeves, era mesmo nisso que estava a pensar ;)

Comment: Coloquei mais informação, como pedido

Answer (score 1):

A questão aqui é "o que' está sendo negociado(a).
Pela frase que postou, o sujeito aqui é o "valor" e não a "empresa", por isso a escrita está no masculino. Mas eu escreveria de outra forma: "cada empresa tem UM valor que merece ser negociado".

Comment: Faz sentido! mas acho que a frase poderia ter sido melhor escrita. Eu colocaria a empresa como negociada. Parece-me uma questão que via no ensino médio: depende do que quer dizer.